# How to return keywords in a list from multiple sentences?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, keyword

I have a list of keywords which I wish to match in a list of sentences. If found within that sentence than return the found keyword in a list.

What I have tried:

```
sentence = df['List of Content']
list_of_words = ['keyword1','keyword2', 'keyword3']
```

This below works if I choose only one row:

```
[word for word in list_of_words if word in sentence[0]
```

and outputs

```
output: ['keyword1', 'keyword3']
```

The desirable output for all the rows, is a list of keywords that match in the sentence.
Something like this:

```
matching_keywords = [['keyword1', 'keyword3'],['keyword2, 'keyword3'],['keyword1', 'keyword2']..]
```

However, when I run the `for` loop in the entire list it just outputs an empty list `[]`

---

I have also tried a nested for loop:

```
kwords = []
for row in MCC:
    for x in list_of_words:
        if x in row:
            kwords.append(x)
```

It either gives me an empty bracket list again `[]` or it just creates a long list of the keywords repeating themselves.

What is the mistake am I making? Anyone can try to help me with the logic/solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend your initial approach by doing the following.

```
[[word for word in list_of_words if word in row] for row in sentence]
```

---

**Explanation:** This amounts to nested list comprehension. For each row, we want a list of keywords that appear in that row. With list comprehension, this should be written as

```
[<list of keywords in row> for row in sentence]
```

On the other hand, if you have a specific row that you're looking at (for instance, `row = sentence[0]`), then as you state in your question the list of keywords that appear in this row can be obtained with `[word for word in list_of_words if word in row]`. Putting this together leads to the result I wrote above, namely

```
[[word for word in list_of_words if word in row] for row in sentence]
```

Comment: For future references, can you just explain the logic?

Comment: @OnikRahman See my latest edit. I hope that clarifies whatever it was that you didn't understand. If not, it would be helpful if you could spell out what needs to be explained.